# Python updating list affects other list

Tags: python, list, python-3.5

Apologies if this has been answered somewhere else. I've searched stack overflow but could not find an answer to this problem.

i do not understand why list L1 is modified even after i create a temp list and put the new rows in there and assign it to list L2.

As far as i can see, i am not copying any list beside temp_list so there should be no link in memory to list L1.

Thanks in adavance

```
>>> L1 = []
>>> a = ['this','is','a','test','message']
>>> L1.append(a)
>>> b = ['this','is','another','good','message']
>>> L1.append(b)
>>> print (L1)
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'message'], ['this', 'is', 'another', 'good', 
'message']]
>>> list_copy_L1 = L1[:]
>>> L2 = []
>>> temp_list = []
>>> for row in list_copy_L1:
        if row[3] == 'good':
            row[3] = 'BAD'
        temp_list.append(row)
>>> L2 = temp_list[:]
>>> print (L1)
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'message'], ['this', 'is', 'another', 'BAD', 
'message']]
>>> print (L2)
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'message'], ['this', 'is', 'another', 'BAD', 
'message']]
>>>
```

Comment: You are operating on a mutable object, when you assign `row[3] = 'BAD'` you are changing the sublist in `L1`. You need to create a copy before changing `row[3]`.

Comment: `row[3] = 'BAD'`  <-- the `row` is a `list` inside of your `L1` so you're affecting `L1` as well. You can verify this with `L1[0] is L2[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i created a copy of list L1, and iterating through the copy instead. The result is still the same with list L1 being modified.

Comment: It's plodding but one way around it is build a new row.     if row[3] == 'good':
        new_row=[row[0],row[1],row[2],'BAD',row[4]]
        temp_list.append(new_row)
    else:
        temp_list.append(row)

Comment: list_copy_L1 = deepcopy(L1) instead of list_copy_L1 = L1[:] solved the issue, Thanks!